# Request Help for reading a line of JS

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what the ? means in the js below?  I did not line wrap the JS code as I did not want to inadvertently change the meaning...

```
errMess = t.origStatus != undefined && t.status != t.origStatus && t.statuseffective == null ? errMess + t.systemname + ": Status effective date invalid.\n" : errMess;
```

I read this as:
errMess =
t.original status not equal to undefined AND
t.status not equal to original status AND
statuseffective equals null **?**  <-- don't know what this means

Comment: Explanation is for C# but meaning is the same
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction in question is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

The code can also be written as:

```
if (t.origStatus != undefined
     && t.status != t.origStatus
     && t.statuseffective == null) {
    errMess = errMess + t.systemname + ": Status effective date invalid.\n";
} else {
    errMess = errMess;
}
```

So, `X = A ? B : C` is equivalent to:

```
if (A) {
    X = B;
} else {
    X = C;
}
```

Additional notes:

- `t.origStatus != undefined` is equivalent to `t.origStatus != null`, because in a equality comparison, `null` is equal to `undefined`. If it's really important to compare against `null` or `undefined`, use the identity operator instead: `t.origStatus === undefined`

Comment: @yes123 I don't need it, but that's the literally translated version of `errMess = .. ? .. : errMess;`. Omitting it would make the answer incorrect.

Comment: @rob-w Thanks that is exactly what I needed... but didn't know how to ask it.  :)

Comment: @Rob-w it wont let me mark your answer as correct for a few more minutes.

Comment: @dlackey: please don't add the else statemtn because as now it's useless

Comment: Rob-w Thanks for the additional notes.  === is a very good tip.  @yes123 - I do see what you are saying but RobW answer still answers the original question of translating it but I do see what you say it is not needed.  I will be removing it from my code to clean things up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shorthand notation for If-THEN-ELSE, which looks as follows:

```
  x ? A : B
```

and means "if x is true than do A, else do B". It's explained well here: http://sanzon.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/the-question-mark-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand version for an if-clause. For more info have a look at [MDN conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
In full length your code would look like this:

```
if ( t.origStatus != undefined && t.status != t.origStatus && t.statuseffective == null ) {
  errMess = errMess + t.systemname + ": Status effective date invalid.\n";
} else {
  errMess = errMess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (t.origStatus != undefined && t.status != t.origStatus && t.statuseffective == null)
      errMess =  errMess + t.systemname + ": Status effective date invalid.\n";
```